# Memory-efficient downsampling (charting) of a growing array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, memory, charts, sampling

A node process of mine receives a sample point every half a second, and I want to update the history chart of all the sample points I receive.
The chart should be an array which contains the downsampled history of all points from 0 to the current point.
In other words, the maximum length of the array should be `l`. If I received more sample points than `l`, I want the chart array to be a downsampled-to-`l` version of the whole history.

To express it with code:

```
const CHART_LENGTH = 2048
createChart(CHART_LENGTH)
onReceivePoint = function(p) {
    // p can be considered a number
    const chart = addPointToChart(p)
    // chart is an array representing all the samples received, from 0 to now
    console.assert(chart.length <= CHART_LENGTH)
}
```

I already have a working downsampling function with number arrays:

```
function downsample (arr, density) {
  let i, j, p, _i, _len
  const downsampled = []
  for (i = _i = 0, _len = arr.length; _i < _len; i = ++_i) {
    p = arr[i]
    j = ~~(i / arr.length * density)
    if (downsampled[j] == null) downsampled[j] = 0
    downsampled[j] += Math.abs(arr[i] * density / arr.length)
  }
  return downsampled
}
```

One trivial way of doing this would obviously be saving all the points I receive into an array, and apply the `downsample` function whenever the array grows. This would work, but, since this piece of code would run in a server, possibly for months and months in a row, it would eventually make the supporting array grow so much that the process would go out of memory.

The question is: Is there a way to construct the chart array re-using the previous contents of the chart itself, to avoid mantaining a growing data structure? In other words, is there a constant memory complexity solution to this problem?

Please note that the chart **must** contain the whole history since sample point #0 at any moment, so charting the last n points would not be acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only operation that does not distort the data and that can be used several times is aggregation of an integer number of adjacent samples. You probably want 2.

More specifically: If you find that adding a new sample will exceed the array bounds, do the following: Start at the beginning of the array and average two subsequent samples. This will reduce the array size by 2 and you have space to add new samples. Doing so, you should keep track of the current cluster size `c`(the amount of samples that constitute one entry in the array). You start with one. Every reduction multiplies the cluster size by two.

Now the problem is that you cannot add new samples directly to the array any more because they have a completely different scale. Instead, you should average the next `c` samples to a new entry. It turns out that it is sufficient to store the number of samples `n` in the current cluster to do this. So if you add a new sample `s`, you would do the following.

```
n++
if n = 1
    append s to array
else        
    //update the average
    last array element += (s - last array element) / n
if n = c
    n = 0 //start a new cluster
```

So the memory that you actually need is the following:

- the history array with predefined length
- the number of elements in the history array
- the current cluster size `c`
- the number of elements in the current cluster `n`

The size of the additional memory does not depend on the total number of samples, hence `O(1)`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood "start at the beginning of the array and average two subsequent samples". Should I literally take a[0] and a[1], average them and put them in place of a[0], moving back the array one place? Or should I average a[0] and a[1], a[2] and a[3] and so on til the end of the array and have as a result an array of half length?

Comment: This is what I meant: `a0 := 0.5(a0+a1); a1:=0.5(a2+a3); a2:=0.5(a4+a5); ...`